# Is there a natural way by which I can hold my erection for more than a hour? How do I maintain my erection after ejaculation?

Tags: penis, ejaculation, erection, sexual-penetration

Good evening, dear friends, I am a 'new' male pornstar. I wanna know that is there any natural way, without any pills/capsules/surgery kind of stuff, to hold my erection for more than a hour? It's very necessary friends because it's the real part of my job! Secondly, how do I maintain my erection after ejaculating once? Thank you.

Comment: Viagra can help, I managed to keep a erection after ejaculation even without viagra, if I'm horny enough...but I'm young (21) so it could be that

Answer (score 2):

Problems with erections can be caused by a physical condition, and they can be caused by psychological factors.  Treating any physical or psychological underlying condition should help. Your GP can suggest possible treatment options.

Treating erection problems caused by psychological factors can be more challenging. However, most men who persevere with treatment find the problem resolves.

If you are concerned that things are not going as they should, you should seek advice from a doctor or licensed mental health professional who can see you in person and learn the important parts of your history (medical, social, and psychological).

You can learn to delay climax.

> There are a number of self-help techniques you can try before seeking medical help.
>
> These include:
>
> - masturbating an hour or two before having sex
> - using a thick condom to help decrease sensation
> - taking a deep breath to briefly shut down the ejaculatory reflex (an automatic reflex of the body, during which ejaculation occurs)
> - having sex with your partner on top (to allow them to pull away when you are close to ejaculating)
> - taking breaks during sex and distracting yourself by thinking about something completely different (Source: [NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/3055.aspx?categoryid=118&subcategoryid=120))

but you cannot naturally maintain erection after ejaculation.

As [NetDoctor](https://www.netdoctor.co.uk/conditions/sexual-health/a12026/the-penis-and-how-it-works/) points out:

> At orgasm, the signalling from the brain changes dramatically. There is a sudden increase in noradrenaline production from nerves in the genitalia. This seems to both trigger orgasm and contract the muscle fibres in the corpora cavernosa and their supplying arteries. As a result of this the blood flow into the penis reduces.